# The returned value not defined

Tags: python, python-3.x

I am creating a guessing game and I have created two functions. One to take the user input and the other to check whether the user input is correct.

```
def getGuess(maxNum):
    if maxNum == "10":
        count=0
        guess = -1
        guessnum = [ ]
        while guess >10 or guess<0:
            try:
                guess=int(input("Guess?"))
            except:
                print("Please enter valid input")
        guesses.append(guess)
        return guesses
        return guess

def checkGuess(maxNum):
    if maxNum == "10":
        if guess>num1:
            print("Too High")
        elif guess<num1:
            print ("Too Low")
        else:
            print("Correct")
            print (guesses)
```

and the main code is

```
if choice == "1":
    count = 0
    print("You have selected Easy as the level of difficulty")
    maxNum= 10
    num1=random.randint(0,10)
    print (num1)
    guess = 11
    while guess != num1:
        getGuess("10")
        checkGuess("10")
        count = count+1
    print (guess)
```

Although the function returns the users guess the code always takes the guess as 11. If I don't define guess, it doesn't work either. Please help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, you are returning two values. A `return` statement also acts as a `break`, so the second `return` will not be called. Also, you are not storing the returned value anywhere, so it just disappears.

Here is your edited code:

```
def getGuess(maxNum):
    if maxNum == "10":
        guess = -1
        while guess >10 or guess<0:
            try:
                guess=int(input("Guess?"))
            except:
                print("Please enter valid input")
        return guess

def checkGuess(maxNum, guess, num1):
    if maxNum == "10":
        if guess>num1:
            print("Too High")
        elif guess<num1:
            print ("Too Low")
        else:
            print("Correct")
            return True
        return False

if choice == "1":
    count = 0
    print("You have selected Easy as the level of difficulty")
    maxNum= 10
    num1=random.randint(0,10)
    print (num1)
    guess = 11
    guesses = []
    while guess != num1:
        guess = getGuess("10")
        guesses.append(guess)
        hasWon = checkGuess("10", guess, num1)
        if hasWon:
            print(guesses)
            break
        count = count+1
```

---

```
You have selected Easy as the level of difficulty
2
Guess?5
Too High
Guess?1
Too Low
Guess?2
Correct
[5, 1, 2]
>>>
```

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer it helped me. I didn't know that return acts as a break as well sorry about that but could you briefly tell me what the below piece of code does.                                                                   if hasWon:
       print(guesses)
       break
    count = count+1

Comment: So if you have won, it prints all the guesses you have done, then exits the `while` loop so it doesn't keep asking you for input. The `count = count+` is after the `if` statement, so if you haven't won, it adds one to `count`, which I expect is the number of guesses used.

Comment: Hi, how did                                              hasWon = checkGuess("10", guess, num1) this statement become a statement to check whether the user has won. Isn't it just the function used to check the guess (whether it's correct or incorrect)? Thanks you very much. Sorry for the late comment.

Answer (score 0):

You have a programming style I call "type and hope".  `maxNum` seems to bounce between a number and a string indicating you haven't thought through your approach.  Below is a rework where each routine tries do something obvious and useful without extra variables.  (I've left off the initial `choice` logic as it doesn't contribute to this example which can be put into your choice framework.)

```
import random

def getGuess(maxNum):
    guess = -1

    while guess < 1 or guess > maxNum:
        try:
            guess = int(input("Guess? "))
        except ValueError:
            print("Please enter valid input")

    return guess

def checkGuess(guess, number):
    if guess > number:
        print("Too High")
    elif guess < number:
        print("Too Low")
    else:
        print("Correct")
        return True

    return False

print("You have selected Easy as the level of difficulty")

maxNum = 10

maxTries = 3

number = random.randint(1, maxNum)

count = 1

guess = getGuess(maxNum)

while True:
    if checkGuess(guess, number):
        break

    count = count + 1

    if count > maxTries:
        print("Too many guesses, it was:", number)
        break

    guess = getGuess(maxNum)
```

A couple of specific things to consider: avoid using `except` without some sense of what exception you're expecting; avoid passing numbers around as strings -- convert numeric strings to numbers on input, convert numbers to numeric strings on output, but use actual numbers in between.

Comment: I am sorry for my lack of knowledge as I am a beginner but could you please tell me more about what you meant by maxNum bouncing between a number and a string. And thank you for your input.

Comment: @RavinduGamage, I was referring to code like `if maxNum == "10":` and `maxNum= 10`, which looking at your code, performed no useful purpose.